# sgplot legend order (except default options)

Tags: graph, sas

The default options for `grouporder` is `data`. But if my data starts with `Sat` and different colors are assigned to `Sat`,`Sun` etc, then the legend order either begins with `Sat(input data order)` or with alphabetical order.

But I want to force the order to be `Mon - Sun`. Of course I can create another variable **myorder** `1 for Mon` and `7 for Sun` then group by **myorder**. But in this way the legend shows `1,2,3..`instead of `Mon Tue ...`

sample data:

```
Date   DayofWeek myorder Sale
3Jan15 Sat       6       20.1
4Jan15 Sun       7       31.1
5Jan15 Mon       1       19.1
```

[This](http://blogs.sas.com/content/graphicallyspeaking/2014/08/03/legend-order-in-sgplot-procedure/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20tzio%20%28Graphically%20Speaking%29)  may be a solution

But I tried `proc format` (the method used in the above link)but it doesn't help.

Sample data:

```
data _t;
input day dow $ sale;
cards;
1 Thu 22.0
2 Fri 23.1
3 Sat 28.2
4 Sun 30.0
5 Mon 21.1
6 Tue 18.2
7 Wed 16.9
8 Thu 18.0
9 Fri 27.9
10 Sat 27.2
11 Sun 13.9
12 Mon 16.0
13 Tue 18.0
;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PROC FORMAT solution is effective.  Here's an example.  It would be nice if `preloadfmt` existed as an option here, but it doesn't seem to.

Basically we create two formats - an informat (to convert 'Sun' to 1 etc.) and a format (to label 1 with 'Sun').  I name them the same, they don't have to be.

```
proc format;
  value dayorder
  1='Sun'
  2='Mon'
  3='Tue'
  4='Wed'
  5='Thu'
  6='Fri'
  7='Sat'
  ;
  invalue dayorder
  'Sun'=1
  'Mon'=2
  'Tue'=3
  'Wed'=4
  'Thu'=5
  'Fri'=6
  'Sat'=7
  ;
quit;

data _t2;
  set _t;
  dow_order = input(dow,dayorder.);
  format dow_order dayorder.;
run;


proc sgplot data=_t2;
vbar day/group=dow_order response=sale grouporder=ascending;
run;
```